# ServerSocket connection issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, wireless, serversocket

Ive been having an issue with Server Socket connect, i have a program for this little game and am trying to use the sockets to get it to connect, but when i get to `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(53000);` it just stops and freezes, doesn't seem to go anywhere after that or take any connections.  And with `kkSocket = new Socket(duke, 53000);` it just crashes right after that, doesn't seem to be connecting, i have made sure my firewall is not on, i have internet permissions added, and i have tried many different things for the device name, i have put in what i have my device named, tried the current ip address and nothing will go through, i have a galaxy nexus and a nexus 7 tablet, and they both have the problem when trying to communicate with each other, any info would be great, thanks.

```
package com.idlethought.handagedon;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageSelectionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA = "resId";
    private int mImageNum;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String myHand = null;
    private String theirHand = null;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    static ImageSelectionFragment newInstance(int imageNum) {
        final ImageSelectionFragment f = new ImageSelectionFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA, imageNum);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    // Empty constructor, required as per Fragment docs
    public ImageSelectionFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mImageNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA) : -1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // image_detail_fragment.xml contains just an ImageView
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment, container, false);
        mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final int resId = MainActivity.imageResIds[mImageNum];
        mImageView.setImageResource(resId); // Load image into ImageView
        addListenerOnImage();
    }

    public void addListenerOnImage() {
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //String id = String.valueOf(mImageNum);
                String screen = null;
                //final int resId = MainActivity.imageResIdsRed[mImageNum];
                //mImageView.setImageResource(resId); // Load image into ImageView
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity().getApplication());
                getActivity();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(FragmentActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = null;
                Button btnDismiss = null;
                Button btnAccept = null;
                switch (mImageNum) {
                case 0: screen = "ROCK";
                        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_rock_hand, null);
                        btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.decline_rock_selection);
                        btnAccept = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.accept_rock_selection);
                    try {
                        openServer(screen);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case 1: screen = "PAPER";
                        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_paper_hand, null);
                        btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.decline_paper_selection);
                        btnAccept = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.accept_paper_selection);
                    try {
                        findServer(screen);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: screen = "SCISSORS";
                        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_scissors_hand, null);
                        btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.decline_scissors_selection);
                        btnAccept = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.accept_scissors_selection);
                    break;
                case 3: screen = "LIZARD";
                        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_lizard_hand, null);
                        btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.decline_lizard_selection);
                        btnAccept = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.accept_lizard_selection);
                    break;
                case 4: screen = "SPOCK";
                        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_spock_hand, null);
                        btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.decline_spock_selection);
                        btnAccept = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.accept_spock_selection);
                    break;
                default: screen = "ERROR!";
                    break;
                }

                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        /*Insert what the accept button does here*/

                    }
                });

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), 
                //      "test goes here", 
                //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

public void openServer(String hand) throws IOException {
        // YEAHHHH TOAST!!!



        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Open Serverbf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(53000);
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        boolean end = false;
        while (!end){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Open Serveraf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            end = serverSocket.isBound();   
        }    

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Open Serveraftr",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        theirHand = in.readLine();
        myHand = hand;
        out.println(hand);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Their Hand:" + theirHand,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"My Hand:" + myHand,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();

    }

    public void findServer(String hand) throws IOException {
        // YEAHHHH TOAST!!!
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), "Find Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        InetAddress duke = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.137");

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket(duke, 53000);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("could not connect");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("other error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));

        //BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //out.println(hand);
        //myHand = hand;
        //theirHand = in.readLine();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Their Hand:" + theirHand,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"My Hand:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        //stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use try-catch statements to catch and display any errors that are occurring and narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Define "it just crashes". And when you get an exception, don't make up your own messages, especially one as banal and content-free as 'other error'. Print the message that comes with the exception, and preferably the stack trace as well. Otherwise you have no hope of knowing what's going wrong, as you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Could you show us the logs? What's the error?.

Second: When you do this:

```
 while (!end){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),"Open Serveraf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        end = serverSocket.isBound();   
    }
```

After the acceptance of the first connection your server socket will no longer listen because the while condition is false.